# Calling a function from onclick, why is my parameter evaluated as true?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change a "textbox" to display differently depending on which radio button is selected. This box is simply a div section with id "output". When I run the following javascript, my parameters seem to be ignored and "hi" is inserted no matter which button I press. Is this a problem with Javascript equality operators, or something with the way in which I've done my function calls?

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("medium").onclick = size(1);
  document.getElementById("big").onclick = size(2);
  document.getElementById("bigger").onclick = size(3);
};

function size(param) {
  if (param === 3) {
     document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "hi";
  }
}
```

Comment: `= size(1);`  this notation will cause to call of the function and to `onclick` will be set the result of the executed function

Comment: `.onclick = function() {size(1);};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementById("medium").onclick = size(1);
```

Sets the onclick property to the **result** of the size function. Not to the function pointer.

So this is equiverlant to:

```
var x = size(1);
//x is null
document.getElementById("medium").onclick = x;
```

Wrap you function in another function so that you set the onclick to a **function pointer** not the result, i.e.:

```
document.getElementById("medium").onclick = function() {size(1);};
```

Comment: Thanks! Initially just fixing the code with your solution didn't work, as I had other function fragments hanging out which kept size(3) from working. Cleaned up, no issues.